# EF Difference between Context.DbSet().SingleOrDefault and Context.Entry

Tags: entity-framework, navigation-properties

If I need to get an entity from the database with Navigation properties populated, it seems I can perform the following two queries:

```
Context.Set().Include().SingleOrDefault();
```

or

```
Context.Entry(entity).Reference().Load();
```

Is there any difference (performance or otherwise) between the two?

Answer (score 2):

Yes different:

A quick check of EF5 source Code:

```
/// <summary>
/// Calls Load on the underlying <see cref="T:System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.IRelatedEnd"/>.
/// 
/// </summary>
public void Load()
{
  this.ValidateNotDetached("Load");
  this._relatedEnd.Load();
}
```

So I conclude the difference is

**Include goes to Db,**

**Load checks context first.** If not there then loads.

DOCU on LOAD says

```
 /// Loads the entity from the database.
 /// Note that if the entity already exists in the context, then it will not overwritten with values from the database.
```